# Browsing to IP and port number displaying raw html 400 bad request

Tags: apache, redirect, numbers, ip, port

Setup HTTPS and a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. Browsing to just the IP address with or without HTTP and HTTPS works great and redirects perfectly. But while browsing to X.X.X.X:443 the web server is displaying the 400 bad request in raw html. Can I either disable the 400 bad request or be able to redirect those requests to HTTPS? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*If* such is possible, it would depend on which web server you are using and you didn't specify that.  However...

**Doing so would actually be a bad idea** as it would encourage people to use HTTP (no S) to connect to your secure server.  In doing so, they would send their request in plaintext.  If the system just returned a "301 Moved Permanently" to the HTTPS url, the second request (with reply) would be protected but you still would have leaked the request to a potential attacker during the first attempt.